# MEAN stack app 503 error on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mean-stack

I have an issue with an app that works as intended locally but gives me a 503 error on Heroku open trying to register:

In the browser console I get:

```
POST https://radiant-mesa-64296.herokuapp.com/user/new 503 (Service
Unavailable)
```

In heroku logs:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/user/new"
host=radiant-mesa-64296.herokuapp.com
request_id=91b0a791-ca3c-43b1-a946-fe819ec03a22 fwd="100.1.170.182"
dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Here is what my server.js looks like:

```
'use strict';

let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let logger = require('morgan');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();

//.env
let dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();

let mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/skycast')

let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', (callback) => {
  console.log('mongoose connected');
})


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


let user = require('./controllers/usersController');
let weather = require('./controllers/weatherController');
let location = require('./controllers/locationsController');

app.use('/user', user);
app.use('/weather', weather);
app.use('/location', location);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));

let server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log('server running');
})
```

I never ran into this issue with any other deploying and would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: On which port you application is listening? It seems `3000` to me, but you are trying to access application on port `443`.

Comment: Yes it's port 3000, but where is port 443 coming from?..I don't believe I set that...

Comment: No, you hit `https://radiant-mesa-64296.herokuapp.com` which listen for secured connection over port `443`. May herokuapp is proxying request from `443` to `3000`

Comment: I fixed it by replacing mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/skycast')
with the mongourl provided...I had to hard wire it unfortunately...